# Animate vertical slide not working

Tags: jquery

http://iamprincess.com.hk/test/final2.html

The horizon slide(left to right) is working, but there's a problem on the vertical slide (top to bottom), it won't slide, what's the problem?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 177: `var slidesH = $('.slidesH');` should be `var slidesH = $('.slideH');`

You have an S too much in slide**s**H.

So it dosen't wrap it inside slide slideInnerH which does the "moving" part :)